# PHP code to track infinite levels of referrals and count

Tags: php, mysql, counter, referrals, mlm

am currently working on making a php code that would count all users referred directly and indirectly a person. In my mysql database, each user have a column called "upline" which is the referrer.

*P.S The referral system is by referral link by the way.

[image: graphical example of user with 6 referrals]

From the above picture example, the following is seen:
A referred **B & C**; B referred **D & E**; C referred **F & G**; G referred **H** only at the moment.

"A" has total of 6 direct and indirect referrals already (3 from left and 3 from right). assuming, this referral process continues deep down the ladder infinitely,my question is: **what php code would count the total current number of referrals under "A" from his right (separately) and left (separately)?**. In the little example above, we can easily count his left to be '3' and right to be '4'. I use PHP and MYSQL database (database table is user and i have column for username and upline).

Please, am still a newbie to many php coding, help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: [Managing hierarchical data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)